# Jquery file download no callback working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am using the `jquery.filedownload` plugin with asp web api to download a file and display error message from the server.

I have setup the plugin and added cookies to my response as indicated on github: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

My file is being downloaded successfully, however callbacks are not working.

**Js**

```
var url = "/WebApi/PayrollBatches/GetBatchCsv?batchId=" + batchId;
$.fileDownload(url, {
 successCallback: function (url) {
       alert('success');
 },
 failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        alert('error');  
 }
 });
return false; 
//this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
```

**Asp Web Api**

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBatchCsv(int batchId)
    {
        string csv;
        try {
            using (var Dbcontext = new RossEntities()) {
                PayrollBatchExport dal = new PayrollBatchExport(Dbcontext);
                csv = await dal.GetBatchCsv(batchId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "CustomErrorCode", 42 } };
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, myCustomError);
        }

        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("fileDownload", "true");
        var cookiePath = new CookieHeaderValue("path", "/");
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        response.Content = new StringContent(csv);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Export.csv";
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie, cookiePath });
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return response;
    }
```

**Edit**

Below is what my browser console looks like when the server responds with error 500:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after spending some time with Fiddler, the problem was with a cookie. Notice this code inside the `jquery.fileDownload.js`:

```
function checkFileDownloadComplete() {
    //has the cookie been written due to a file download occuring?

    var cookieValue = settings.cookieValue;
    if (typeof cookieValue == 'string') {
        cookieValue = cookieValue.toLowerCase();
    }

    var lowerCaseCookie = settings.cookieName.toLowerCase() + "=" + cookieValue;

    if (document.cookie.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseCookie) > -1) {

        //execute specified callback
        internalCallbacks.onSuccess(fileUrl);
...
```

The success callback is being called only if server returns a cookie as project page says, however the API controller wasn't returning this cookie correctly. This code works well for me and is also described of [official docs](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies)

```
public class PayrollBatchesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBatchCsv(int batchId)
    {
        string csv;
        try
        {
            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(@"~\Files\testfile.csv");
            csv = File.ReadAllText(path);// await dal.GetBatchCsv(batchId);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "CustomErrorCode", 42 } };
            HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, myCustomError);
            errorResponse.Content = new StringContent("error: " + ex.ToString());
            return errorResponse;
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        // Set Cookie
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("fileDownload", "true");
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        // -------------
        response.Content = new StringContent(csv);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Export.csv";
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return response;
    }
}
```

Please note, that for demo purposes I am not retrieving CSV data from DAL but from a testing file as the above code shows. Also, to be complete here, I am attaching the client side code:

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <button id="btn" type="button">get</button>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fileDownload.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var url = "/api/PayrollBatches/GetBatchCsv?batchId=1";
                $.fileDownload(url, {
                    successCallback: function (url) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Edit:** fail callback

Comment: will take a look and revert. Thank you

Comment: the success callback is now working. The problem is that the success callback is always getting hit even when the server returns 500. Which kind of undermines the whole point of why i am using this plugin for. In your test scenario are you managing to get the error message via the failCallback?

Comment: @JustLearning I am not managing fail scenario but let me check :)

Comment: @JustLearning I edited my answer. Please try it and let me know. I am not an author of this jquery plugin but after some debugging it may seem as a fix.

Comment: i added the changes, but there seems to be no effect. It is still calling the successCallback even when there is a 500 server response code

Comment: @JustLearning for me it works fine. How exactly do you cause the exception on the server? Are you sure you really don't return `HttpStatusCode.OK`? Try to check the network traffic in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130411/discussion-between-justlearning-and-ivan-sivak).

Comment: I was following another post which was given in Java. It made it look like there were two cookies needed. But your post here shows it is one cookie with a Path = "/". What you put here was exactly what I needed to get my JQuery.FileDownloader.js working with my WebApi Controller Action Method.